# How can I split Sub-Arrays within a array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array somewhat like this:

```
Arr=[[1,2],[3,5]];
```

I want to split this into two different arrays like `[1,2]` and `[3,5]`. How do I do that in JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

They already *are* two different arrays. JavaScript doesn't have multi-dimensional arrays, it has arrays of arrays, and so in your question there are **three** arrays: The one referenced by `Arr` and the two referenced by that array at indexes `0` and `1`.

So if you want to use those separately from `Arr`, just do so:

```
var first = Arr[0];
var second = Arr[1];
// do something with `first` and `second`
```

Answer (score 0):

you can call them by their index,

```
var arr1 = Arr[0];
var arr2 = Arr[1];
```